# node.js OpenID provider implementation

Tags: node.js, openid, openid-provider

Does anyone know good OpenID provider implementation in node.js? Maybe node module?

I am using passportjs to implement Relaying Party functionality.

Comment: Did you find one? I'm looking for one too. Ideally, one which supports attribute exchange as well.

Comment: I am writing a dirty working sketch, reading OpenID specification. If i finish it, I will publish.

Comment: What's the problem with passport?

Comment: @Mallox, passport is an openid client (Relaying Party). I haven't problems with passport. I am looking for OpenID server (provider).

Comment: Any update on your implementation, yttrium?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [openid-provider](https://npmjs.org/package/openid-provider).

It's an OpenID provider implementation in node and you can use it with express.

Comment: Same (limited in functionality and not very stable) I already implemented by myself.

Answer (score 9):

A [certified](http://openid.net/certification/) OpenID Connect provider module (`oidc-provider`) is available over at [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oidc-provider).

```
npm install oidc-provider
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this one: https://github.com/ammmir/node-oauth2-provider.

In NPM:

```
npm install openid-connect
```

It only supports OAuth2 however, so if you need earlier versions of the protocol, you have to look elsewhere.

Comment: I don't need oauth provider. Thank you. I am found it earlier.
May be that may work as I need: https://github.com/agmoyano/OpenIDConnect